# Storing arima predictions into empty vector in R

Tags: r, vector, prediction

I am having some trouble storing arima predictions into an empty vector. The problem is arima predictions give you predictions and standard errors. There are two columns of values. I cannot seem to store the values in an empty vector. I tried to create two empty vectors and bind them together, but it did not solve the problem.

My intention is to simulate 1000 observations. Use the first 900 observations to make 100 predictions. The list of values have to update. For example, use 900 observations to predict the value of the 901th observation. Now use 901 observations, including the predicted 901th observation, to predict the 902th observation. Repeat until you use 999 observations to predict the 1000th observation. I hope to figure out how to store multiple values into a vector.

The empty vector I hope to contain 100 predictions is called Predictions1.

```
# Create Arima Series #

ArimaSeries1 = arima.sim(n=1000, list(ar=c(0.99), ma=c(0.1)))+50
ts.plot(ArimaSeries1)
acf(ArimaSeries1)

ArimaSeries2 = arima.sim(n=1000, list(ar=c(0.7,0.2), ma=c(0.1,0.1)))+50
ts.plot(ArimaSeries2)
acf(ArimaSeries2)

ArimaSeries3 = arima.sim(n=1000, list(ar=c(0.6,0.2,0.1), ma=c(0.1,0.1,0.1)))+50
ts.plot(ArimaSeries3)
acf(ArimaSeries3)

# Estimate Arima Coefficients using maximum likehood #

ARC1 = arima(ArimaSeries1, order = c(1,0,1))
ARC2 = arima(ArimaSeries2, order = c(2,0,2))
ARC3 = arima(ArimaSeries3, order = c(3,0,3))

# Estimate Arima Coefficients with 900 observations #

AR1 = arima(ArimaSeries1[1:900], order = c(1,0,1))
AR2 = arima(ArimaSeries2[1:900], order = c(2,0,2))
AR3 = arima(ArimaSeries3[1:900], order = c(3,0,3))

# Create for-loop to make one prediction ahead for 100 times #

PredictionsA = rep(0,100)
PredictionsB = rep(0,100)
Predictions1 = cbind(PredictionsA,PredictionsB)

for(a in 1:100){ Forcasting1 = predict(arima(ArimaSeries1[1:900+a], order=c(1,0,1)), n.ahead=1)}
Predictions1[a] = Forcasting1
```

R would give me this error message:

> Warning message: In Predictions1[a] = Forcasting1 :   number of items
>   to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I would be grateful for any suggestions. Any explanations on where I went wrong is also appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Predictions1 <- array(NA, c(100,2)) 
for(a in 1:100){ 
  Forcasting1 = predict(arima(ArimaSeries1[1:900+a], order=c(1,0,1)), n.ahead=1)
  Predictions1[a,] = unlist(Forcasting1)
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. If I'm not asking too much, why did the solution you posted work? I'm new to R and would like to learn more about storing output from functions into vectors.